# What is the definition of double right arrow operator ( >> ) in Spock?

Tags: groovy, spock

There are code snippets in [this Spock wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/Interactions) that involve double right arrow operators (>>). For example:

```
setup:
subscriber.isAlive() >> true
```

So, what does the >> operator mean in this case? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The right-shift (`>>`) operator defines the return value or behavior of a stubbed method. You can find more information under [Stubbing](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1-SNAPSHOT/all_in_one.html#_stubbing) in the [reference documentation](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1-SNAPSHOT/index.html).

Comment: I'm guessing they used the operator overloading feature of groovy to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485861/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-operator-in-groovy