# Flexible JVM language for creating domain specific languages?

Tags: java, prolog, dsl, jvm-languages

Say I am interested in creating a JVM-based implementation of Prolog.
I would like to know if it is possible to use an existing JVM language for emulating the Prolog syntax, instead of relying on a Prolog parser that takes as an input a text file with Prolog code.

In Prolog you can define facts, rules, and the tricky part is that you can also define new operators at a very fine-grained level: you can specify the operator position, precedence and associativity.

Some simple examples below:

**Facts:**

```
father(john, peter).
mother(susan, peter).
male(john).
...
```

**Rules:**

```
parent(X, Y) :- father(X, Y).
parent(X, Y) :- mother(X, Y).
```

**Operators:**

```
op(100,xfx, is-father-of)
```

**Rule using operator:**

```
X is-father-of Y :- male(X), parent(X,Y).
```

I took a look to Groovy but [it does not seem to allow to define new operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485861/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-operator-in-groovy). To the best of my knowledge Scala allows to define operators but I do not think a statically-typed language will help me here. Is there a JVM language that could help me to do this?

Am I condemned to make use of a Prolog parser if I want to do this in the JVM?

Comment: This is a wild guess, but parsing Prolog is going to be one of the easier things to do. Implementing a (working) Prolog VM in on top of the JVM is quite a task.

Comment: I know it pretty well. And I am not saying that I will actually end up doing it :) . It is just a question asked out of curiosity.

Comment: You can always check out JIProlog, which is rather a Prolog implementation in Java (not a JVM Prolog), but I guess it should be possible to reuse some of their code.

Comment: Why do you think a statically-typed language won't help you? I think to the contrary.